# Nested Python module imports

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a python file `main.py` that runs code from two sub-directories

I am currently doing

`from dir1 import class
from dir2 import module`

within `main.py`

But the class and module also have imports dependent on sub-directories within dir1 and dir2, so when I launch the main python file I get a `ModuleNotFoundError` saying it cannot find the subdirectories within dir1 and dir2

Comment: I really don't think we can answer this with the information you've given. What's the directory structure? What import statements are you using in each file?

Comment: Please post the file structure and the headers of the other files you are attempting to import modules from

Comment: First, you need to stop thinking about subdirectories and start thinking about packages. In the simplest case, where `main.py`, `dir1`, and `dir2` are all in a directory on `sys.path` and neither of `dir1` nor `dir2` is itself on that path, you'll end up with top-level packages named `dir1` and `dir2`, and you can do absolute imports against them accordingly. But if you've got some other structure, things could be more complicated, and the only way to understand it will be to understand the package structure that your directory structure implies.

Comment: @EastonBornemeier What do yo umean by "headers"?

Comment: @abarnert I poorly described the lines at the top of the file where the imports occur as headers

Comment: @abarnert above has made a great point so please pay some attention to this - in Python, you import _modules_, not _files_ from directories (even though a module is a collection of files in a directory somewhere). I suggest spending some time reading this up to section 5.2 inclusive (or a related tutorial), it'll clarify a lot: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html

Comment: Also: if `dir1` and `dir2` are independent self-contained programs (with their own modules), then perhaps the most correct way to invoke them from your `main.py` program is by launching a separate Python process. E.g. you can use `subprocess.run([sys.executable, '-m', 'module'], cwd='dir1')`, which will launch a separate Python process where `dir1` is the root of `sys.path`. For sufficiently complex enough child programs this is often the simplest integration path.