# Python nested import 'ModuleNotFound' error

Tags: python, python-3.x, nested, python-import

I have the following folder structure:

- high_level.py (top level)
- low_level (directory)

  - low_level_script.py (within 'low_level')
  - config.py  (within 'low_level')

And the following code:

**high_level.py**

```
from low_level import low_level_script

low_level_script.test_fun()
```

**low_level_script.py**

```
import config
def test_fun():
    return config.A
```

**config.py**

```
A = 1
```

If I do the following, at the top level, I get an import error.

```
import high_level

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'config'
```

Why is this, and what is the best way of making the script.py able to import config.py, in a way that makes script.py importable from its own directory, and the directory above?

The reason why I'm interested in this is because I want to have a pytest tests in test_high_level.py, and test_low_level.py pytest script that import the high-level and low-level scripts.

I'm using Python 3.7. I see another question asking something similar here, but there doesn't seem to be a concrete suggestion, except reading all of this documentation.

[Nested Python module imports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51252214/nested-python-module-imports)

https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html

This question also seems similar - it recommends using libname, but I'm not completely sure how this addresses the problem.

[Python: ModuleNotFound Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50546451/python-modulenotfound-error)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use relative imports you should precede the module name with a dot.

```
import .config
```

or use absolute imports instead

```
from low_level import config
```

Comment: The 2nd case works perfectly. If I change low_level.py to 'from low_level import config' then everything works well. If I change it to 'import .config', then I get a syntax error. I also don't entirely understand what was wrong with my initial effort, or what the established best-practice is for cases like this?

Comment: Do you have any __init__.py?

Comment: adding empty \__init__.py files to the folder structure above doesn't help the .config error. I also don't understand why this would be needed for Python 3.7?

Comment: After updating the said import statement, would the low_level_script.py run as usual if run on its own inside the low level directory?

Comment: If you need to use it in a deeper tree, you should use relative imports.